# How to serve WASM files in Django

Tags: python, django, webassembly, emscripten

I compiled my C file to wasm using:

```
emcc main.c -s USE_SDL=2 -O3 -s WASM=1 -o main.js
```

I'm only using WASM to manipulate a canvas. There is no JS code other than the "glue" js code.

I now have a directory (outside of Django, just somewhere in my Documents folder) with these files:

```
- home.hml
- main.c
- main.js
- main.wasm
```

Which I can serve using whatever webserver eg

```
python3 -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1
```

And view the animation in the browser. And it works. No problems so far.

I want to serve home.html from Django now. My URLs.py has:

```
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
```

and views.py has:

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

I have copied home.html to `app/templates/app`

I then copied main.js to `app/static/app`

Then I modified home.html to replace:

```
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="{% static 'app/main.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I don't know what to do with main.wasm. Should this also go into the static folder or into the project root? Do I need to add an explicit import somewhere for this? How can I get my home.html to behave the same as it was with a simplehttpserver, but when being served from Django?

Please note that all DOM elements in home.html are displaying correctly as it stands other than the canvas. So I'm relatively certain that everything is set up correctly, except for the fact that main.wasm is not accessible.

Comment: @pts that worked thanks! Network tab showed it was looking at /app/static/main.wasm I put it in the static folder and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the HTTP requests made by the browser in the Network tab of the developer tools of the browser. Maybe the path in the URL is wrong or Django returns an incorrect Content-Type.